# Efeito de transição modal

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic2, ionic3

Bem, eu estou com a seguinte dúvida, eu tenho um [ModalController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/) quando estou executando em iphones, a transição de entrada vem de baixo para cobrir a tela de tola.

Com esta biblioteca, posso mudar essa transição? Eu preciso da transição para aparecer a partir do meio da tela, isso deve acontecer da mesma maneira para telefones Android, iPhone e Windows.

Estou tentando fazer assim:

```
openModal() {
 let options: NativeTransitionOptions = {
  direction: 'down',
  duration: 500,
  slowdownfactor: 3,
  slidePixels: 20,
  iosdelay: 100,
  androiddelay: 150,
  fixedPixelsTop: 0,
  fixedPixelsBottom: 60
};

this.nativePageTransitions.slide(options);
  let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(SlideAccessibility, null);
  myModal.present();
}
```

Percebi pela documentação que tenho como passar options para a chamada, talvez nela eu consiga fazer o efeito que preciso, porém como a documentação é pobre não achei nada sobre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionei o problema, fui verificar o código até encontrar os tipos de transições possíveis. Assim descobri o que pode ser passado em `options` o código final ficou assim:

```
openModal() {
 let options: ModalOptions = {
  showBackdrop: false,
  enterAnimation: 'modal-md-slide-in',
  leaveAnimation: 'modal-md-slide-out',
};

this.nativePageTransitions.slide(options);
  let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(SlideAccessibility, null, options);
  myModal.present();
}
```

Para ficar de dica a classe é esta e estas são as opções que podem ser passadas como parametro:

```
export interface ModalOptions {
  showBackdrop?: boolean;
  enableBackdropDismiss?: boolean;
  enterAnimation?: string;
  leaveAnimation?: string;
  cssClass?: string;
}
```

E estes são os 4 tipos de transições possiveis ja preconfigurados:

```
modal-slide-in [Refere ao efeito de ios, baixo para cima]
modal-slide-out [Refere ao efeito de ios, saida cima para baixo]
modal-md-slide-in [Refere ao efeito do android, meio para cima]
modal-md-slide-out [Refere ao efeito do android, cima para meio]
```